# Cannot get custom taxonomy filter in media list view to work

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I have created a filter dropdown in Media list view to filter media files based on selected term. The dropdown rendered OK with the custom taxonomy item. But the filter is not working at all. Irrespective of the term I select from this dropdown, all media items are being listed. No filtration is happening.

Here is my code to create the filter dropdown (in functions.php):

```
function media_add_content_category_filter_dropdown()
{
    $scr = get_current_screen();
    if ( $scr->base !== 'upload' ) return;

    $terms = get_terms('media_content_category', array('hide_empty' => false));
    if ( $terms ) {
        printf( '<select name="%s" class="postform">', esc_attr( 'mcfdd' ) );
        print( '<option value="">All Categories</option>');
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            printf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>', esc_attr( $term->term_id ), esc_html( $term->name ) );
        }
        print( '</select>' );
    }
}

add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'media_add_content_category_filter_dropdown');
```

And this is the code I am using to for filtration purpose:

```
function media_content_filter($query) {
    if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if (isset($_GET['mcfdd']) && $_GET['mcfdd'] == -1) {
            $query->set('mcfdd', '');
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','media_content_filter');
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution to display taxonomy filters on media library and filter:

```
//[[START] - Add custom taxonomy dropdown to media library
function media_add_content_category_filter_dropdown() 
{
   global $wp_query;

   // check we're in the right place, otherwise return
   if ( 'upload.php' != $pagenow )
     return;

   $tax_slug = 'media_content_category';
   $tax_obj = get_taxonomy( $tax_slug );

  // check if anything has been selected, else set selected to null
  $selected = isset($wp_query->query[$tax_slug]) ? $wp_query->query[$tax_slug] : null;

   wp_dropdown_categories( array(
     'show_option_all'   => __($tax_obj->label . ' - All'),
     'taxonomy'          => $tax_slug,
     'name'              => $tax_obj->name,
     'orderby'           => 'name',
     'selected'          => $selected,
     'hierarchical'      => true,
     // 'show_count'        => true,
     'hide_empty'        => false
  ) );

}
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', 'media_add_content_category_filter_dropdown');
```

To filter posts by custom taxonomy

```
function media_tsm_post_convert_id_to_term_in_query($query) 
{
   global $pagenow, $typenow;

// check we're in the right place, otherwise return
if ( 'upload.php' != $pagenow )
    return;

$filters = get_object_taxonomies( $typenow );

foreach ( $filters as $tax_slug ) {
    $var = &$query->query_vars[$tax_slug];
    if ( $var != 0 )  {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $var, $tax_slug );
        $var = $term->slug;
    }
  }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'media_tsm_post_convert_id_to_term_in_query');
//[END] - Add custom taxonomy dropdown to media library
```

Comment: I added the complete code here please check it out : https://deltafrog.net/wordpress-media-library-add-custom-taxonomy-with-quick-edit-in-list-view/